# scrlttr2 pagenumbers in header or footer on all pages (including the first one)

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrlttr2

I am trying to combine [a nice footer on all pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426016/nexthead-and-nextfoot-problem-in-multi-page-letter-with-koma-and-srclttr2) with [pagenumbers on all pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578016/show-page-number-same-footer-on-the-first-page-of-a-letter-in-koma-scrlttr2). I have `firsthead=off` since I need a logo in the place of the back address. If I remove `\chead*{\pagemark}` from the first link and add `\pagemark` to `\setkomavar{firstfoot}` I get the pagenumer next to the footer like that: [image]

but I would like it to have it in this position [image]

The footer can take more space on the button if needed to. Also it is ok if the pagenumbers are on the top, like in the first example. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt, 
version=last, 
fromalign=left, 
backaddress=true, 
foldmarks=on, 
fromphone=off, 
fromemail=off, 
parskip=half, 
firsthead=off]{scrlttr2} 
%
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}  


\usepackage{blindtext}
            
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}   

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}  % Signatur wird bündig gesetzt

%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% Absender
% 
\newcommand{\mVorname}{stupid company GmbH} 
\newcommand{\mNachname}{\& Co. KG} 
\newcommand{\mStrasse}{Somestreet. 1} 
\newcommand{\mStadt}{Somecity} 
\newcommand{\mPLZ}{22223} 
\setkomavar{date}{} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{\mVorname{}~\mNachname{}}               % Name 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mStrasse{}\\{}\mPLZ{}~\mStadt{}}    % Adresse
\setkomavar{frombank}{SomeBank\\ 
            IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\BIC: AAAAAAAAAAA}

\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright 
Versandanschrift:\\
\vfill
Some Guy   \\
23423 Blablubbing       \\ 
Blabistan               \\
Telefon
} 

\makeatletter
\@setplength{locvpos}{4.8cm}
\@setplength{locwidth}{7.5cm}
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}
\makeatother

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\showfields{address}% show the address box


\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage}%
}

% header and footer first page:
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{% changed ->
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}%
  \parbox{\useplength{firstfootwidth}}{%
      \rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}  
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Geschäftsinformation:}}\\ 
          persönlich haftende Gesellschafterin:\\ 
          stupid company Verwaltungs-GmbH\\
          Amtsgericht Somecity, HBR 111111 \\
          Handelsregister: Somecity HRA222222 \\
          \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\;}l@{}}USt-IdNr.:& DE 000000000 \\
          WEEE-Nr.: & DE 00000000 \end{tabular}\\
          Geschäftsführer: Some Guy \\
          Sitz Somecity 
        \end{tabular}
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{\usekomavar*{frombank}:}} \smallskip \\
          \usekomavar{frombank} \smallskip \\
          Somethirdbank  \\
          IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\
          BIC: CCCCCCCCCCC
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{} \smallskip \\ 
          Someotherbank \\
          IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\
          BIC: BBBBBBBBBBB
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
  }%
}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putUL{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
]{likefirstpage.foot}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{likefirstpage.foot}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{\pagemark}

\begin{document} 

%recipient  
\begin{letter}{%    
Max Musterkunde \\
Teststraße 2    \\
55555 Teststadt \\
Schweiz         \\ 
     }

 \AddToShipoutPicture{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-20.0pt,xshift=-10]%
        at (current page.north east)
        {\includegraphics[height=18mm]{example-image}};
    \node [anchor=north west,yshift=-20.0pt,xshift=47]%
        at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=15mm]{example-image}};
    \node [anchor=south east,yshift=0pt,xshift=0]%
        at (current page.south east)
        {\includegraphics[height=13mm]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }     

% 
%\setkomavar{title}{Titel} 
\setkomavar{subject}{BETREFF} 
% 
\opening{}
%

\Blindtext

\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Edit: I put

```
    \begin{textblock*}{3cm}(9.5cm,28.5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
        \pagemark
    \end{textblock*}
```

in the `firstfooter` and it is pretty stupid, but I have no other solution yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a centered page number below the tables add:

```latex
\par\centering\pagemark\par
```

after the parbox containing the third table, but inside the outer parbox.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt, 
  parskip=half, 
  firsthead=off
]{scrlttr2} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% not needed in this example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\newcommand{\mVorname}{stupid company GmbH} 
\newcommand{\mNachname}{\& Co. KG} 
\newcommand{\mStrasse}{Somestreet. 1} 
\newcommand{\mStadt}{Somecity} 
\newcommand{\mPLZ}{22223} 
\setkomavar{date}{} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{\mVorname{}~\mNachname{}}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mStrasse{}\\{}\mPLZ{}~\mStadt{}}

\setkomavar{frombank}{SomeBank\\IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\BIC: AAAAAAAAAAA}
\newcaptionname{ngerman}{\banknames}{Bankverbindungen}% caption name for more than one bank
\newkomavar[\banknames]{frombanks}% caption for more than one bank
\newkomavar[\usekomavar*{frombank}]{secondfrombank}
\setkomavar{secondfrombank}{Someotherbank\\IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\BIC: BBBBBBBBBBB}
\newkomavar[\usekomavar*{frombank}]{thirdfrombank}
\setkomavar{thirdfrombank}{Somethirdbank\\IBAN:DE00 0000 0000 0000 0000 00\\BIC: CCCCCCCCCCC}

\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright 
  Versandanschrift:\\
  \vfill
  Some Guy\\
  23423 Blablubbing\\
  Blabistan\\
  Telefon
} 

\setplength{locvpos}{4.8cm}
\setplength{locwidth}{7.5cm}
\setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}

\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
\showfields{address}% show the address box

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage}%
}

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{% <- changed: { added
    \parbox{\useplength{firstfootwidth}}{%
      \rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Geschäftsinformation:}}\\ 
          persönlich haftende Gesellschafterin:\\ 
          stupid company Verwaltungs-GmbH\\
          Amtsgericht Somecity, HBR 111111 \\
          Handelsregister: Somecity HRA222222 \\
          \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\;}l@{}}USt-IdNr.:& DE 000000000 \\
          WEEE-Nr.: & DE 00000000 \end{tabular}\\
          Geschäftsführer: Some Guy \\
          Sitz Somecity 
        \end{tabular}
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{\usekomavar*{frombanks}:}} \smallskip \\% <- frombanks
          \usekomavar{frombank} \smallskip \\
          \usekomavar{thirdfrombank}
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \hfill
      \parbox[t]{0.31\linewidth}{%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
          \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{} \smallskip \\ 
          \usekomavar{secondfrombank}
        \end{tabular}%
      }%
      \par\centering\pagemark\par% <- centered pagemark added
}}}% <- changed: { added

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putUL{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
]{likefirstpage.foot}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{likefirstpage.foot}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  page,
  addvoffset=20pt+.3333em,
  addhoffset=47pt+.3333em,
  addwidth=-47pt-.6666em,
  addheight=-20pt-.6666em,
  mode=picture,
  contents={%
    \putUR{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=18mm]{example-image}\hspace{10pt}}}}%
    \putUL{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\includegraphics[height=15mm]{example-image}}}%
    \putLR{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=13mm]{example-image}}}%
  }
]{logos}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{logos}

\begin{document} 
\begin{letter}{%
  Max Musterkunde\\
  Teststraße 2\\
  55555 Teststadt\\
  Schweiz\\
}

  \setkomavar{subject}{BETREFF} 
  \opening{}
  \Blindtext
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

I have removed options which are not needed in the example. Package `inputenc` with option `utf8` is only needed with outdated TeX distributions. The `tikz` and `eso-pic` code is replaced by a new layer for all layer page styles (`@everystyle@`).

[image]

Comment: you also taught me how to define my own komavars!

Comment: Also a side note: this example works with MikTex, but the current Debian/Ubuntu TexLive package (2019) throws bunch of errors, the PDF is created correctly though. I have installed TexLive 2021 and there are no more errors.

Comment: The outdated TL 2019 needs package `amsmath` for `\;`  (used in a `tabular` declaration).